# flash actionscript 3.0 hide part of an image

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a flash sound mixer application with multiple sound channels, and I am having trouble with the lights beside the volume knob.

Is there a way to hide just a part of an image?

On the image below, image-2 is on top of image-1 to create some kind of volume level indicator effect, and how much of image-2 is shown depends on the value of the volume.

image-url: http://s30.postimg.org/r3ow1g5bl/volume_lights_level.png

I've tried by just reducing the height of image-2, but it looks awful and distorted.

Is there something in flash that works closely the same as CSS's behavior.

example: I'll just make image-2 a background of a shape, and when I reduce the shape's height, the image-background does not get distorted or changes it's height as well.

By searching for solutions, I have come across the mask property, but I don't quite understand how it works, and most of the examples shown are images placed inside circles.

Is the mask property applicable in this situation?

I'm quite new to flash so I don't know a lot of things yet.

Comment: try changing the height in **position** to follow slider, example  `image2.y = slider.y;` instead of actual height in **size** (dont it as  `image2.height = someValue;`. Also you could fine tune the height offset like so.. `image2.y = slider.y - 10;`.. adjust that 10 to see how it goes

Comment: I already thought of that. But how do I hide the rest of the image?
It should not show anywhere above the red circle.
http://s2.postimg.org/jsmehyk3d/img2.png

Comment: Position a mask (rectangle shape over the "lights" area). The shape itself must be inside a movieClip or Sprite since only those can deal with masking. The shape must be same size as lights area. Now tell Flash that grey `image2.mask = mask_MC;` and it will only be visible where its pixels touch the mask_MC area. The mask can have zero alpha so it'll be invisible to the eye `mask_MC.alpha = 0;`..

Comment: Just to add again.. **dont** adjust any heights. This is a matter of **Y** position. Mask and Coloured should in sample place as they are and only the greybar moves up/down over lights except greybar has a mask controlling how much section is visibie. If you need a sample code let me know.. See **[this tutorial](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3masking/)** for help to set-up a movieClip mask if needed.

Comment: I got it working now, many THANKS!!! heres how I did it.  
  
Imported img-2 to stage, converted it into symbol(type:Movie Clip), assigned instance name: img2_mc.  
  
I created a new layer for the mask, drawn a rectangle using rectangle tool, converted it also to symbol(type:Movie Clip), assigned instance name: mask_mc.  
  
Then applied the mask to img2_mc.  
`
/* the code */
img2_mc.mask = mask_mc;

function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void{
 var volumeKnob_y = volSliderKnobOn.y + 12; // adjust it to the center of the knob

 mask_mc.height = volumeKnob_y;
}
`

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use a mask.

**How to programmatically create your mask**

Put an occurrence of your image named `myImage` on the stage, and put over this occurrence a mask named `myMask` with the same dimensions. You can apply myMask mask to myImage using it's `mask property` like below:

**Main Timeline**

```
myImage.mask = myMask;

function mouseMoveHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    myMask.height = myImage.y - e.stageY;
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
```

You have just to adapt this code to your animation, in the function where you click your button.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now, many THANKS @VC.One. heres how I did it.

Imported img-2 to stage, converted it into symbol(type:Movie Clip), assigned instance name: img2_mc.

I created a new layer for the mask, drawn a rectangle using rectangle tool, converted it also to symbol(type:Movie Clip), assigned instance name: mask_mc.

Then applied the mask to img2_mc.

/* the code */
`img2_mc.mask = mask_mc;`

`function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void{`
    `var volumeKnob_y = volSliderKnobOn.y + 12;` // adjust it to the center of the knob

```
mask_mc.height = volumeKnob_y;
```

`}`